# React Native: download PDF to local storage (ios)

Tags: ios, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

I have the following function to download a PDF from my server:

```
  const downloadInvoice = (invoiceId) => {
    const path = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir}/${invoiceId}.pdf`;
    RNFetchBlob.config({
      fileCache: true,
      path,
    }).fetch('GET', `${Urls.base}/pro/invoice?invoiceId=${invoiceId}`, {
      ...authorizationHeaders
    }).then((response) => {
      RNFetchBlob.ios.openDocument(path);
    }).catch((error) => {
      Alert.alert(error);
    });
  };
```

When I run this code, the document opens up on my iPhone and I can see the PDF file. The problem is, I cant find the PDF document anywhere after I close the window. It seems like the document is stored in cache, but I want it to store in a folder accessible on my iPhone for later user (or to print it or transfer it to my laptop).

Path looks like: `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AD1F85AC-456F-321A-A4B2-1B248F1134C1/Documents/20-02-2020-01-02.pdf`. Also, when I console.log response.path(), it has the same path.

I'm using [rn-fetch-blod](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob), but I see this package is unmaintained. If somebody has a good alternative, I'm happy to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this keys in `info.plist` for `iOS`

```
<key> UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
```

source : https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/212